# I have a 10 USB HUB that turns off when I turn on a device from the wall socket

Tags: usb-2

if I turn on a device from the wall socket the HUB turns off and then back on again,is that normal..?

It did come with a power adapter but that got damage so its not powered,only powered by the PC.

Comment: It is not normal, but you should probably call an electrician or use a different wall socket for the other device if that bothers you. Apparently the wall socket is not built for serving two power intensive devices at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The available power on a single USB 2 port [is limited to 500mA](https://superuser.com/questions/690074/what-is-the-power-output-of-a-usb-port). If you power several devices and they together use more than 500mA, you are working outside of the USB specification. You have to use a power adapter for the hub.